# Can someone explain to me how to approach this problem and what the objective of a problem like this is?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Calculate the derivative.

$$\frac {d}{dx} [ 12 x^{5/3} - 7 x^{-2} -12 ]$$

I have no prior knowledge of calculus and am struggling terribly to understand this conceptually. I really have no idea how to even begin this problem.

Comment: Are you in a calculus class?  Why are you trying to calculate a derivative if you have "no prior knowledge of calculus"?

Comment: Um, if you have no  knowledge of calculus there is no way at all you can do a calculus problem.  If you know some calculus this is a very straightforward derivative.   This uses the rule $\frac{d}{dx}x^p = px^(p-1)$ which holds for all numbers p, not just integers.  It should be very straightforward to solve it now.

Comment: @fleablood if you have more than one character in an exponent use the notation ^$\{\text{[Insert Math Here]}\}$. For example, wrapping e^{x^2+y} in $\$$ symbols will produce $e^{x^2+y} $.

Comment: all right.  It'd be nice if comments had a preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to apply the [basic rules of differentiation](http://www.math.brown.edu/UTRA/derivrules.html):

$$\begin{align}
&\frac {d}{dx} [ 12 x^{5/3} - 7 x^{-2} -12 ]\\
=&\;\frac {d}{dx} [ 12 x^{5/3}] - \frac {d}{dx} [7 x^{-2}] -\frac {d}{dx} [12 ]\tag{sum rule}\\
=\;&\frac {d}{dx} [12x^{5/3}] - \frac {d}{dx} [7 x^{-2}] -0\tag{constant rule}\\
=\;&12\frac {d}{dx} [x^{5/3}] - 7\frac {d}{dx} [x^{-2}] \tag{constant multiple rule}\\
=\;&12\frac{5}{3}(x^{2/3}) - 7(-2)(x^{-3}) \tag{power rule}\\
=\;&20x^{2/3} +14x^{-3} \tag{simplification}\\
\end{align}$$

This [site](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx[12%20x%5E%285%2F3%29%20-%207%20x%5E%28-2%29%20-12%20]) can be useful for you.

Comment: Yes, correct but the OP has no prior knowledge of calculus.....

Comment: @imranfat You are right but, even so, the OP have to calculate a derivative... (It is not needed to know calculus to calculate derivative of elementary functions. You only need to know some formal rules (or some software). My answer provides a basic source for this purpose.)

Comment: Thank you! That site has become very useful in calculus !

Answer (score 1):

Some rules for differentiation ($D$ is the differential operator):
$$\begin{align}D(f(x) + g(x)) &= Df(x) + Dg(x) & \text{($D$ is additive)}\\ D(af(x)) &= aDf(x) & \text{($D$ is degree $1$ homogeneous)} \\ D(1) &= 0 \\ D(x^k) &= kx^{k-1}\end{align}$$

Now let's use these on your problem:

$$\begin{align}D(12x^{5/3}−7x^{−2}−12) &= D(12x^{5/3}) + D(-7x^{-2}) + D(-12) \\ &= 12D(x^{5/3})-7D(x^{-2})-12D(1) \\ &=12\left(\frac 53\right)x^{2/3} -7(-2x^{-3})-12(0) \\ &=20x^{2/3}+14x^{-3}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Some basics:

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}[f(x) + g(x)] = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(x) + \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}g(x) $$

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}c = 0\quad\hbox{(c is a constant)}$$

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}c\times f(x) = c \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(x)$$

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}x^p = px^{(p-1)}$$

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(x)g(x) = \left[\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(x)\right]\times g(x) + \left[\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}g(x)\right]\times f(x)$$

I know that last one is hard to remember but you won't need it for this problem.

Just apply the appropriate rules and it is straightforward.